# how to make application supporting orientation

Tags: interface-orientation

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

view1=[[BIDViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"BIDViewController" bundle:nil];
[self willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:view1.interFaceOrientaion1 duration:1];
 }

-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

     -(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{

if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
{
    lable1.frame=CGRectMake(100 ,102 ,225 , 21);
    [self setInterFaceOrientaion2:toInterfaceOrientation];
}

if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
{
    lable1.frame=CGRectMake(250, 116,225 ,21);
        [self setInterFaceOrientaion2:toInterfaceOrientation];
}
else if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){
    lable1.frame=CGRectMake(250, 116, 225, 21);
    [self setInterFaceOrientaion2:toInterfaceOrientation];
}
```

}

@end

BIDViewController class could be able to access the property interFaceOrientation2,
But BIDViewController2 class could not be able to access the property interFaceOrientation
thought @class BIDViewController is present.

how to access this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling properties change as per below 
Check orientation as below in viewWillApear method

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation=[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
[self willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:orientation duration:1];
```